# Render section or display error message

Tags: visualforce, rerender, pageblock, conditional

I have a requirement where I want a section to render depending on a value of a controller variable. If the section is not rendered I want an error message to be displayed. I have the following piece of code

```
<apex:pageblock rendered="{!AModel.enableSection}">
```

I want something like this

if enablesection is true render page block
else display String message 'Section cannot be rendered'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<apex:pageblock rendered="{!AModel.enableSection}">

<apex:pageMessages rendered="{!NOT(AModel.enableSection)}"/>
```

Use apexPageMessage with Rendered

And in controller use

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,'Section cannot be rendered'));
```

Comment: How would I pass the static value to the page message? I would not be able to return it form a method

Comment: @Rimii you need to use `ApexPages.addMessage` to add the pageMassage in your page.